# Integration by u subsitution

Tags: integration, complex-integration

So i have this integral

$$\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}}x^2 \ln(x^3-3)\,dx.$$

I was thinking of using u subsitution to make everything easier.

I made $u = x^3-3$ and $du = 3x^2dx$.

So I would then re-write my integral as

$$1/3\int_{\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{3+e}} \ln(x^3-3)\.$$

How would I proceed from here. Should I plug in the integral values? Wouldn't I need to integrate the $\ln()$? Should I use u substitution again? Please help!

I already asked this question, so don't mark it as a duplicate. Unfortunately I couldn't understand what other people were writing.

Comment: It seems to me that i explicitaly wrote not to mark it as duplicate :))))

Comment: That you don't understand the answers is no reasons to post a question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you  integrate by substitution, you have the express the differential form under the integral sign: $f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ as a differential form $\;g(u)\,\mathrm d u$, and replace the bounds for the integral in $x$ with corresponding bounds for the new variable $u$.

*Some details in this case*:

If you set $u=x^3-3$, you have $\mathrm d u=3x^2\,\mathrm d x$, so
$$\int x^2 \ln(x^3-3)\,dx=\int  \ln(x^3-3)(x^2\,dx)=\int\ln u\,\frac13\mathrm du=\frac13\int\ln u\,\mathrm du .$$

Now let's take care of the bounds:

- $x=\sqrt[3]4\leftrightarrow u=4-3=1$,
- $x=\sqrt[3]{3+\mathrm e}\leftrightarrow u=3+\mathrm e-3=\mathrm e$

Thus the integral is
$$\frac13\int_1^{\mathrm e}\ln u\,\mathrm du=\frac13(u\ln u-u)\biggr|_1^{\mathrm e}=\frac13.$$

Comment: Thankyou ! Unfortunately i can't ask other questions so maybe i'll post it here. What about the integral from e to 1 of t²ln(t²)dt? I was thinking of using u subsitution but it doesn't work out... so what about integration by parts?

Comment: Turn  it into the integral of  $2t^2\ln t$. The latter can be calculated with in integration by parts, so the `\ln` disappears from the r.h.s.

Comment: How would i do that ? By u subsitution?

Comment: No, you factor out $2$, set $u=\ln t$ and   $\mathrm d v = \ln t\,\mathrm dt$, then use the formula for integration by parts $$\int u\,\mathrm dv=uv-\int v\,\mathrm d u.$$

Comment: How would i factor out 2? Where is it coming from...

Comment: It comes from $\ln t^2=2\ln t$ (if $t>0$). You just have to use that the  integral is linear.

Comment: Oh okay... so you are just rewriting the equation to make it simpler? Moreover , the derivative of lnt is 1/T? Am i correct?

Comment: And wouldn't dv=t squared?

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $\ln t$ is $1/t$. As to $\mathrm dv$ it is $(\ln t)\, \mathrm d t$, whence $v=\dotsm$.

Answer (score 2):

After your substitution, your integral should be
$ 1/3 \int_1^e \ln(u) du$.

Comment: I don't understand the e and the 1. I know that you got them from subsitution the t's of the integral into the equation , but woulnd't the answer then be e-1 ? Why are you plugging the e and 1 back into the integral ?

Comment: From the lower bound of $4^{1/3}$ we need to cube and subtract by 3 to get the bound in terms of u.  Same for the upper bound.

Comment: I still don't understand. Sorry.

Comment: The substitution is $u = x^3-3$.  To find the bounds in terms of $u$, you simply plug in the x values into this equation.

Comment: But the answer as you said was e and 1. But the answer is 1/3. How come?

Comment: And woulnd't the subsition be ln(u) ? Why does the ln dissappeaar?

Comment: I would get ln(e) and ln(1)

Comment: Perhaps you should practice the substitution method on a simpler integral.  The mechanics will be the same, but with fewer manipulations.

Comment: I think it got it . Please tell me if i am correct. I am left , when subsituting the t's, with 1/3 ln(e)- 1/3 ln(1)= 1/3-0= 1/3. Correct?

Comment: yup, that's correct

Comment: Thanks for the help.. unfortunately i can't post another question , so i'll post it here. I have the integral from e to 1 of t²ln(t²)dt. I tried u subsituion but it doesn't seem to work ? Should i use integration by parts? How would i do that ? If you could show me the steps it would be of great help !